# How to import imported package's vendor package

Tags: go

I am using etcd's wal package (https://godoc.org/github.com/coreos/etcd/wal) to do write-ahead logging. wal has `go.uber.org/zap` in its vendor packages. In wal's create function `func Create(lg *zap.Logger, dirpath string, metadata []byte) (*WAL, error)`, I need to pass in `zap.Logger`.

I have tried to import `go.uber.org/zap` but go compiler complains "type mismatch" when I pass in `zap.Logger`.

```
package main 

import (
"github.com/coreos/etcd/wal"
)

func check(e error) {
    if e != nil {
        panic(e)
    }
}

func main() {

    metadata := []byte{}
    w, err := wal.Create(zap.NewExample(), "/tmp/hello", metadata)

    // err := w.Save(s, ents)


}
```

How should I use `zap.Logger` in my project?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [package's type cannot be used as the vendored package's type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38091816/packages-type-cannot-be-used-as-the-vendored-packages-type)

Comment: Have you tried : add `go.uber.org/zap` in the vendored dependencies of your own project, and build from your project ?

Comment: @LeGEC, it gives a type mismatch.

Answer (score 2):

It seems like the package `github.com/coreos/etcd/wal` is not meant to be used outside of the etcd project. If you really need to use it, please, follow the steps below.

1. Place the following code in the `$GOPATH/src/yourpackage/main.go` file.

   ```
   package main

   import (
       "fmt"

       "go.etcd.io/etcd/wal"
       "go.uber.org/zap"
   )

   func main() {
       metadata := []byte{}
       w, err := wal.Create(zap.NewExample(), "/tmp/hello", metadata)
       fmt.Println(w, err)
   }
   ```
2. `mkdir $GOPATH/src/yourpackage/vendor`
3. `cp -r $GOPATH/src/go.etcd.io $GOPATH/src/yourpackage/vendor/`
4. `mv $GOPATH/src/yourpackage/vendor/go.etcd.io/etcd/vendor/go.uber.org $GOPATH/src/yourpackage/vendor/`
5. `go build yourpackage`

Comment: I dont think this works.  Anyone can confirm?  Even if it did, its not a very sustainable way of using this.